# MySQL regular expression to return all records where at least one word matches between 2 columns

Tags: mysql, regex

My database has 2 columns that contain text. When it has say 3 records as follows:

```
rec#   col1             col2
1      my name is       fred is
2      john             mike
3      today not sat    not it sat
```

I would appreciate help constructing a regular expression that will return record numbers:

1 -> because "is" matches

3 -> because "'not" and "sat" match (i.e. at least one match exists)

Comment: Tablescans, start your engines !

Comment: only 2 columns? what is rec#, some kind of id?

Comment: That was just to illustrate. The query will be SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE <regexp goes here>; (it's the regular expression I'm stuck with)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this as:

```
select t.*
from table t
where col1 rlike replace(col2, ' ', '|');
```

This turns `col2` into a regular expression.  So, note that this answer will be very sensitive to the contents of `col2`.  If it contains regular expression special characters, then this probably will not work.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this and it seems to work in most cases but I see it misses out some for example where  col1 contains "MY NEW BOTTLING COMPANY" and col2 contains "UP  BOTTLING  COMPANY". I can see this must be due to inconsistency in the number of blank spaces in between characters so the replace does not work perfectly. Is there a simple elegant solution here as trim/ ltrim/ rtrim will not work?

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "matches"?

This `SELECT` will find the rows where `col1` contains at least one of the words `is` or `not` or `sat`:

```
SELECT rec_num
    FROM tbl
    WHERE col1 REGEXP '[[:<:]](is|not|sat)[[:>:]]';
```

This says that at least one of those words exists in *both* `col1` and `col2`:

```
SELECT rec_num
    FROM tbl
    WHERE col1 REGEXP '[[:<:]](is|not|sat)[[:>:]]'
      AND col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]](is|not|sat)[[:>:]]';
```

Change `AND` to `OR` to ask if one of the words exists in *either* (or both) column.

If you need the *same* word (is/not/sat) to match *both* `col1` and `col2`, that is more complex:

```
SELECT rec_num
    FROM tbl
    WHERE ( col1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]is[[:>:]]'
        AND col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]is[[:>:]]' )
       OR ( col1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]not[[:>:]]'
        AND col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]not[[:>:]]' )
       OR ( col1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]sat[[:>:]]'
        AND col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]sat[[:>:]]' );
```

If you mean something else, practice asking precise questions.

**Addenda**

It is not practical in SQL to discover which words (if any) are in common between two text fields.  Such a task would be better done in an application programming language (PHP, Java, Perl, ...).

Comment: No this is supposed to work for any word. is, not, sat are just for illustration.

Comment: Where does the 'word' come from?  Is there application code generating this query?  Are you manually writing the query?  Are there exactly 3 words you need to test for?

Comment: I'm simply trying to select all records in the table where at least one word in column `col1` (text-type) also appears in column `col2` (also text type). So the word can be anything because the contents of the table cannot be predetermined.

Comment: does that mean it's impossible?

Comment: I mean that the code is soooo ugly that I don't want to ponder how to do it.  It would probably take a stored procedure, a cursor, `substring_index`, a loop, constructed `SELECTs`, and some repetitious expressions.  It would be tedious to write and extremely slow to run. With Perl or PHP, it is `split`, one hash, and not much more.